# DNS for hosting root domain on one server and a particular path on another

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

I am soon to transfer a website to my server for a client. The site is currently at www.xxx.com. On there they have a third party app in a folder on the server at www.xxx.com/app/.

The app is massive, and won't fit on our server, so they want to keep it hosted where it is and just move the rest of the site to my server.  But they want to keep the url the same.

So...
www.xxx.com -----> My server
www.xxx.com/app/ -----> Their server

Is there any way I can achieve this with DNS?

Comment: No.  DNS provides a mapping between IP addresses and hostnames.  "`www.xxx.com/app/`" is not a hostname.  Use an http redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible in many cases, but not with DNS.  Instead, you can setup this directory `/app` as a reverse proxy in your web server that then forwards the request to the original server.

I say "many cases", as some apps can make this difficult, e.g. if they work with absolute instead of relative links and path names.

Answer (score 0):

No. DNS only cares about the hostname part. What you could do (in addition to the previous suggestion of a reverse proxy) would be to setup a subdomain app.xxx.com.

You could then setup redirect/rewrite rules so that www.xxx.com/app forwarded to app.xxx.com and on the original server requests to app.xxx.com are served from the app folder.